# Is this partial index considered a compound index in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb that I created the index below for.

```
let keys = { lastModifiedDate: -1 };
let options = { 
    expireAfterSeconds: 120, 
    partialFilterExpression: { active: false }
};
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, function (err, db){
   if (err) throw new Error(err); 
   db.collection("users").createIndex(keys, options)
});
```

Another way (using a shell command) to create that index is:

```
db.eventlog.createIndex(
  { lastModifiedDate: -1 },
  { expireAfterSeconds: 120, partialFilterExpression: { active: 'false' } }
);
```

In the mongoose schema, I show the below:

```
lastModifiedDate: {
 type: Date, 
 default: new Date()
 },
 expireAfterSeconds: {
  type: Date
 }
```

and the whole thing operates as it should, with the document being automatically deleted after 120 seconds when the condition that "active" is "false" is fulfilled.

What I would like to know is does this index:

`{ expireAfterSeconds: 120, partialFilterExpression: { active: 'false' }}`

count as a compound index?

I have read that in Mongodb, you can only have a maximum of 32 fields if you create a compound index. I plan to have more than 32 fields in the collection.

Comment: I tested it roughly by adding fields to the mongoose schema so that the total number of fields was more than 32, including the partial index, and I was able to do operations on the database without difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not a compound index, you have only one field:

```
{ lastModifiedDate: -1 }
```

That is what counts.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that in Mongodb, you can only have a maximum of 32 fields if you create a compound index. I plan to have more than 32 fields in the collection.

You can have "only" 32 fields in that compound index.

There is no limit to the number of fields you can have in the collection itself.

```
db.eventlog.createIndex(
  { lastModifiedDate: -1 },
  { expireAfterSeconds: 120, partialFilterExpression: { active: 'false' } }
);
```

And this is not a compound index anyway. It only has a single field in it.